# Convert JSON to array of property options

Tags: json, swift, swift4

I have a JSON file:

```
{
  "sceneSettings":[
    {
      "showsStatistics":false,
      "autoenablesDefaultLighting":false,
      "antialiasingMode":"multisampling4X",
      "debugOptions":[
        {
          "showPhysicsShapes":false,
          "showBoundingBoxes":false,
          "showLightInfluences":false,
          "showLightExtents":false,
          "showPhysicsFields":false,
          "showWireframe":false,
          "renderAsWireframe":false,
          "showSkeletons":false,
          "showCreases":false,
          "showConstraints":false,
          "showCameras":false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get the debugOptions and return them as an array of [`SCNDebugOptions`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scndebugoptions) for use in ARkit.

I currently have a struct `DebugOption`:

```
struct DebugOption: Decodable, Loopable {
    let showPhysicsShapes: Bool = false
    let showBoundingBoxes: Bool  = false
    let showLightInfluences: Bool = false
    let showLightExtents: Bool = false
    let showPhysicsFields: Bool = false
    let showWireframe: Bool = false
    let renderAsWireframe: Bool = false
    let showSkeletons: Bool = false
    let showCreases: Bool = false
    let showConstraints: Bool = false
    let showCameras: Bool = false
}
```

And im decoding the json file using:

```
class SceneSettingsFactory {

    func parseJSON() -> SceneSettings? {
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ModelsData", withExtension: "json") {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let jsonData = try decoder.decode(ResponseData.self, from: data)

                return jsonData.sceneSettings
            } catch {
                print("error:\(error)")
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

struct ResponseData: Decodable {
    var model: [Model]
    var sceneSettings: SceneSettings
}

struct SceneSettings: Decodable {
    let showsStatistics: Bool = false
    let autoenablesDefaultLighting: Bool = false
    let antialiasingMode: AntialiasingOption = .none
    let debugOptions: DebugOption
}
```

I'm unsure of how to efficiently convert the Bool values into an array of their corresponding `SCNDebugOptions` if their value is true.

I started by adding the following to my DebugOption struct but it doesnt feel like the best way.

```
func getOptionArray() -> [SCNDebugOptions] {
    var optionsArray = [SCNDebugOptions]()
    let allPropertyValues = self.allProperties
    allPropertyValues.forEach { property in
        guard let valueIsTrue = property.value as? Bool else { return }
        let propertyAsOption = keyStringAsOption(property.key)
        if valueIsTrue {
            optionsArray.append(propertyAsOption)
        }
    }
}

private func keyStringAsOption(_ propertyString: String) -> SCNDebugOptions {
    switch propertyString {
        case ""
    }
}
```

Any insight or help would be great as this feels long winded.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct ResponseData: Decodable {
    var model: [Model]
    var sceneSettings: SceneSettings
}
```

Looks like wrong. Your sceneSettings is array but your type is `SceneSettings`. I suggest you to create something like this:

```
struct ResponseData: Decodable {
    var model: [Model]
    var sceneSettings: [SceneSetting]
}
```

Also you should update your `SceneSettings` struct to `SceneSetting`